# Is there an analog of Bash's Ctrl+Z & fg in Powershell?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, powershell

I find the combination of Ctrl+Z with subsequent fg on Bash very handy, it's like a command line analog of alt+tab, so I can switch from viewing one file to the output of a running process etc.

Is there an analog for Windows Powershell? I can't google anything but the "pause" which just stops the current running process but doesn't let me switch to the command line and then back.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, sort of - using the psjob commands (requires Powershell 2)

http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/background-jobs/

Edit: The site has the names wrong. It's 'start-job' instead of 'start-psjob'

See 'help start-job' for the complete (and correct) information.

Comment: Strange thing, I don't have Start-PSJob in my Powershell.
$host.Version.Major yields 2; doesn't that mean I have Powershell 2?
I have pscx installed, maybe it gets in the way?

Comment: The site appears to be wrong - its 'start-job' instead of 'start-psjob'

Comment: and start-job does not have the Command parameter

Comment: See 'help start-job' and 'help start-job -examples'

Comment: anyway, thanks for the suggestion --- I'll try to figure it out

Comment: however this means that I have to think ahead and start everything as a background process, which isn't as nice as Ctrl+Z on whatever is running right now

Comment: Hence my 'sort of'. As far as I know PS doesn't have a way to background the current task.

Comment: It has other problems, too:

1) Receive-Job marks the job as Complete, so one can do it only once.

2) When invoked, it just spits out whatever the job has produced, so no "switching to" less, for example.

Comment: @IgorBaltiyskiy `Receive-Job` does not mark the job as complete. If the job is still running, you can run `Receive-Job` again to get any additional output since the last `Receive-Job` was run. The job is marked as complete when the command finishes.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry. Well, if the job is something like "less", it finishes immediately after it is created, and the "additional output" can be retrieved only the first time. So it's nothing like doing "fg".

Comment: `Receive-Job -keep` can be used to retrieve results later on, if that's any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already are running a process and you just want to pause it for a while, I have found out that when I select text in the console, it will pause the running proces until you press enter to copy the selected text.

This is a silly trick of course, but worked for me. I'm just putting it here in case it's useful for someone...

Comment: silly trick indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

similar command for

```
fg
```

in powershell is to use

```
Debug-Job -Id <job-id>
```

This will made the specified job in the foreground. to view more about job commands in powershell use

```
Get-Command -noun job
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not at all the same as ctrl-z, a tabbed console like ConEmu is a simple Windows solution to task switching in a single window.