# Is there a windows equivalent to kill -STOP (or Ctrl-Z)

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to suspend a program under windows in the same way as `kill -STOP` would do for Linux.

There seems to exist [something using powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/465238/is-there-an-analog-of-bashs-ctrlz-fg-in-powershell), but apart from that in a "vanilla" windows? Preferably working for a program that has not been launched via a command window

Comment: You could use an external tool like [PsSuspend](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx). Other more involved ways are discussed in a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows).

Comment: The [Windows Resource Monitor](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-resource-monitor-windows-7) `resmon.exe` has a GUI feature to suspend processed. This tool was introduced in `Windows 7`.

Comment: powershell **is** vanilla Windows and is always available since Windows Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Axel Kemper answers in comments to original post, `resmon.exe` is a builtin solution that does a pretty similar job